# XSLT XML to XML transformation, validate, create a node/element dynamically

Tags: xml, validation, xslt, required

I'm transforming XML to XML using the following XSLT. I need to validate the source XML for required element. If the sibling node's value is missing for the required node then create a new node.
Here is the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data Schema="XML A">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute[not(Type=following::Type)]">
        <Attributes type="{Type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                 select="../Attribute[Type=current()/Type]" mode="out"/>
        </Attributes>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="out">
        <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<XML>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <id>331</id>
            <Name>Enviornment</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value>Development</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>79</id>
            <Name>Retail</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value></Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>402</id>
            <Name>Gender</Name>
            <Type>category</Type>
            <Value>Men</Value>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</XML>
```

And if the required elements  is missing then it should create the following XML. I have multiple required elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data Schema="XML A">
  <Attributes type="common">
    <Attr id="331" name="Enviornment" value="Development" />
    <Attr id="79" name="Retail" value="" />
  </Attributes>
  <Attributes type="category">
    <Attr id="402" name="Gender" value="Men" />
  </Attributes>
  <errorCodes>
    <errorCode>"value for Retail is missing."</errorCode>
  </errorCodes>
</Data>
```

And if it can be done using the following XSLT then it will be a big plus. Thanks in Advance.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="type" match="Attribute" use="Type"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data Schema="XML A">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="XML/Attributes/Attribute">
                 <xsl:sort select="Type" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template 
            match="Attribute[generate-id()=generate-id(key('type', Type)[1])]">
        <Attributes type="{Type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                    select="../Attribute[Type=current()/Type]" mode="out"/>
        </Attributes>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="out">
         <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="type" match="Attribute" use="Type"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data Schema="XML A">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="XML/Attributes/Attribute">
                 <xsl:sort select="Type" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <errorCodes>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="XML/Attributes/Attribute" 
                                     mode="errors"/>
            </errorCodes>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template 
            match="Attribute[generate-id()=generate-id(key('type', Type)[1])]">
        <Attributes type="{Type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                    select="../Attribute[Type=current()/Type]" mode="out"/>
        </Attributes>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="out">
         <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute"/>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="errors"/>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute[Value='']" mode="errors">
        <errorCode>"value for <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> is missing."</errorCode>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the desired output:

```
<Data Schema="XML A">
    <Attributes type="common">
        <Attr id="331" name="Enviornment" value="Development" />
        <Attr id="79" name="Retail" value="" />
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes type="category">
        <Attr id="402" name="Gender" value="Men" />
    </Attributes>
    <errorCodes>
        <errorCode>"value for Retail is missing."</errorCode>
    </errorCodes>
</Data>
```

Comment: I have 1 more question. I have to check for a specific Attributes/Attribute/Type=ComplexAttr. If it is present in the source then I have to create <Attr> inside <Attribute type="common"> else I have to default it to some values. Can you guide me on how to achieve this output.

Comment: 1 more thing the above XSLT is checking all of them. However, I want to validate only specific ones which are required. For example, When node is /Attributes/Attribute/Name=Retail then check the value of /Attributes/Attribute/Value and if it is missing then create an <error> node

Comment: @JohnXsl - you should upvote Iwburk for this excellent work. I did.